# Change the value WPF User Controls

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding

I am creating a UserControl but I can't refresh the values.

When I start the app with a value in the TextBox it's captured. but when I changed the value and touch the button no capture the new value.

This is the User control XAML:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="txtCedula" md:HintAssist.Hint="Cedula"  Text="{Binding txtCedula1}" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" Height="40" Margin="113.496,81.01,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="243.5" />
```

And this is the Code VB:

```
Partial Public Class Conductor
    Public Property txtCedula1 As String
        Get
            Return txtCedula.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            txtCedula.Text = value
        End Set
  End Property
End Class
```

Here I'm try capture the value that I'm typing

```
Private Sub btnGuardar_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles  btnGuardar.Click
    validarCampos()
End Sub
Private Sub CaptureValue()
            Dim conductor As New Conductor

            If conductor.txtCedula1 = Nothing Then
                       MessageBox.Show("Ivalid", "SmartTruck", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information)

            End If
    End Sub
```

I always get the invalid message, even when I enter values

Comment: You've not shown us the button click event code. If it calls CaptureValue then this does nothing when there's text in the box

Comment: I'am Sorry. Ready. The message should not come out. Since I receive income

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and adorn you properties with it.  Else if you are binding 
Xaml:

```
 <Textbox Text = "{Binding Test}"' />
```

It knows it can be set once, but not on any updates:

Something like this should work if you are doing MVVM.  You also need to ensure that your ViewModel or whatever class is bound to the datacontext it sounds like you do by saying it shows up the first time though.

Something like this for the ViewModel:

```
Public Class TextViewModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Private _test As String

Public Property Test As String
    Get
        Return _test 
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _test = value
        ' Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
        OnPropertyChanged("Test")
    End Set
End Property

' Declare the event
Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

' Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
Protected Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal name As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I would also add that you need to bind commands as well as collections too if you are going to be doing other things.  Basically the UI thread needs to know what the code thread is doing and you typically implement more functionality through coding helper methods in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new instance of the UserControl:

```
Dim conductor As New Conductor
```

You should access the existing instance of it. If you have declared the UserControl element in the XAML markup of your window you should give it an x:Name:

```
<local:Conductor x:Name="uc" />
```

You can then access it by this name:

```
Private Sub btnGuardar_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles  btnGuardar.Click
    validarCampos()
End Sub

Private Sub CaptureValue()
    If uc.txtCedula1 = Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Ivalid", "SmartTruck", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information)
    End If
End Sub
```